# How to send a data from ESP8266 (Arduino) to PC (Python) over Wifi

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I have an ESP8266 measuring a voltage via its Analog port (1).
I have the ESP8266 successfully connecting to my local WiFi network.
I can successfully command the ESP8266 over the local WiFi with Python using simply requests.get commands. Which I can then action.

```
import requests

try:
    r = requests.get("http://192.168.0.xxx/1/voltage/")
    print(f"Status Code: {r.status_code}")
except:
    print("Failed to send message")
```

Where I am stuck it getting the ESP8266 to send back the voltage value it acquired back to my PC over the WiFi and how to create the correct Python code to listen and collect the data.
I've seen explanations that suggest using an API and sending the data to cloud servers, which I don't want to do if possible.
I've seen examples that suggest setting up socket listeners, unfortuantely I couldn't follow it that well, which left me copying code, which appears to start a listener, but couldn't find a way to get the ESP8266 to send the data in a way it could be captured or if the Python code is even working.

```
import socket

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.bind(("192.168.0.XX", XXXX))
serversocket.listen()

(clientsocket, address) = serversocket.accept()

buffer = ""

while 1:
    data = clientsocket.recv(128)
    datastr = buffer + data.decode('utf-8')
    split = datastr.split("\n")
    buffer = split[-1]
    print(split[:-1])
```

I would probably prefer something simple like a POST if possible.

So basically I'd like to write something in Python that can collect data sent from my ESP8266 directly over my LAN, as well as what ESP8266 code (I'm using C through the Arduino IDE) is required to send the data correctly from the ESP8266 to be collected by the PC Python code.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: For Arduino IDE with ESP8266, there are plenty of examples that come install with the ESP8266 core, including how to send HTTP over WiFi or using a httpclient. For python, the socket is just a physical connection with TCP/IP, what protocol running on top of it is up to you, you can build your own [HTTP POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) request on top of it.

Comment: By examples in the ESP8266 core, do you mean examples in the Arduino ESP8266 library or somewhere else? Do I need to set up sockets first in Python on the PC to use it to receive the HTTP POST from the ESP8266?

Comment: By examples I means click on File -> Examples on Arduino IDE, different Arduino Core/Boards come with different examples/libraries. If you prefer github, you can also find them in [libraries](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the nudge hcheung.
I ended up changing tack.
The ESP8266 can run as a HTTP Server, so I configured the ESP8266 to do that and read the voltage.
This is mostly code from one of the ESP8266 examples, with some extra I added to measure and send the voltage value in bits (0-1024).

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>

#ifndef STASSID
#define STASSID "wifi"
#define STAPSK  "password"
#endif


// my stuff
const int analogInPin = A0;  // ESP8266 Analog Pin ADC0 = A0
int sensorValue = 0;  // value read from the port


const char* ssid     = STASSID;
const char* password = STAPSK;

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

const int led = LED_BUILTIN;

// Set your Static IP address
IPAddress local_IP(192, 168, 0, xxx);
// Set your Gateway IP address
IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 0, x);

IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);
IPAddress primaryDNS(8, 8, 8, 8);   //optional
IPAddress secondaryDNS(8, 8, 4, 4); //optional

void handleRoot() {
  digitalWrite(led, 1);
  server.send(200, "text/html");
  digitalWrite(led, 0);
}

void handleVoltage() {
  if (server.method() != HTTP_POST) {
    digitalWrite(led, 1);
    server.send(405, "text/plain", "Method Not Allowed");
    digitalWrite(led, 0);
  } else {

    // my stuff
    sensorValue = analogRead(analogInPin);
    Serial.print("Voltage: ");
    Serial.println(sensorValue);
    String myVoltageString = String(sensorValue);

    digitalWrite(led, 1);
    String message = "POST form was:\n";
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < server.args(); i++) {
      message += " " + server.argName(i) + ": " + server.arg(i) + "\n";
    }
    server.send(200, "text/plain", myVoltageString);
    digitalWrite(led, 0);
  }
}

void handleNotFound() {
  digitalWrite(led, 1);
  String message = "File Not Found\n\n";
  message += "URI: ";
  message += server.uri();
  message += "\nMethod: ";
  message += (server.method() == HTTP_GET) ? "GET" : "POST";
  message += "\nArguments: ";
  message += server.args();
  message += "\n";
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < server.args(); i++) {
    message += " " + server.argName(i) + ": " + server.arg(i) + "\n";
  }
  server.send(404, "text/plain", message);
  digitalWrite(led, 0);
}

void setup(void) {

  // Configures static IP address
  if (!WiFi.config(local_IP, gateway, subnet, primaryDNS, secondaryDNS)) {
    Serial.println("STA Failed to configure");
  }

  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(led, 0);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("");

  // Wait for connection
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  if (MDNS.begin("esp8266")) {
    Serial.println("MDNS responder started");
  }

  server.on("/", handleRoot);

  server.on("/voltage/", handleVoltage);

  server.onNotFound(handleNotFound);

  server.begin();
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");
}

void loop(void) {
  server.handleClient();
}
```

And then just a simple Python script to request the value.

```
import requests

url = 'http://192.168.0.xxx/voltage/'
server = requests.post(url)
output = server.text

print('The response from the server is: \n', output)
```